# Be it online ads or shopping, the cloud or smartphones, tech markets are more mature

Tags: verbs

> **Be** it online ads or shopping, the cloud or smartphones, tech markets **are** more mature

question 1  :  Why use the "Be"? what ingredients?

question 2:  why does the sentence have two verbs , one is "Be" ,another is " are" ?

Comment: Initial ***be*** there is a ***subjunctive*** usage. Probably best avoided by non-native speakers, because it's a declining usage anyway, that mainly only persists in literary / poetic / oratorical contexts today. Even if we reverse the stylised resequencing of the cited text here,  *Tech markets are more mature, be it online ads or shopping, the cloud or smartphones* isn't very idiomatic today. Arguably the more so because the actual substance of the assertion is bang up-to-date, whereas the *syntax* is at best "dated".

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: Also note that apart from the "stylistically poor" matter of using the subjunctive in your example, it's ***syntactically incorrect***. Because ***markets*** is plural, the pronoun should be too: *Be **they** online ads or shopping, the cloud or smartphones, tech **markets** are more mature.* Or change the actual noun to singular ***the tech market***.

Answer (score 1):

"Be it" means the same as "whether it's", so the sentence could be rephrased:

> **Whether it's** online ads or shopping, the cloud or smartphones, tech markets are more mature.

There are still two verbs (the "'s" means "is"), but hopefully it's clear that there are two clauses here, so it makes sense that there are two verbs